# Combine two single arrays and form an associative array

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, laravel

I have two arrays of data coming from an HTML form.

Array1 (payment_descriptions) looks like this:

```
["1st Desc","2nd Desc","3rd Desc"]
```

And Array2 (payment_amounts) like this:

```
["100.10","10.50","39.99"]
```

Is there a way to combine these arrays (payments) so that the end result will look like this?

```
[{
    "description": "1st Desc",
    "amount": "100.10"
}, {
    "description": "2nd Desc",
    "amount": "10.50"
}, {
    "description": "3rd Desc",
    "amount": "39.99"
}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with simple `array_combine()` and a `foreach()` loop:

```
<?php
$arr1 = ["1st Desc","2nd Desc","3rd Desc"];
$arr2 =["100.10","10.50","39.99"];

$combined = array_combine($arr1,$arr2);
$expected = [];
foreach($combined as $k=>$v){
    $expected[] = ['description'=>$k,'amount'=>$v];
}
echo json_encode($expected,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/1tP4c

*Without* `array_combine()`:

```
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v){
    $expected[$k] = ['description'=>$v,'amount'=>$arr2[$k]];
}
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/6FVHe

Comment: Sorry, I had made a couple of other posts on this site without any issue and I followed the exact same formatting for my questions as I have in the past. How can I improve my questions for next time?

Comment: @Hampkade I've added a link you on my answer. Have a look on that or https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and by the way is that helped?

Comment: i think he wants you to start the sentence with "How" and end it with a question mark.